# Use bluetooth keyboard with a different layout?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, languages, text-layout

I'm Italian, so I use italian language on my tablet (note 10.1), but I have also a bluetooth keyboard with english layout that I use to write little snippets of programmes, the problem is that I don't know how to set english language only for the keyboard. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to use two different languages either on a smartphone or on a tablet is from device standard settings, with device keyboard and also with external USB and bluetooth keyboard.
To use more than one language follow the images: [I can't post images yet]

```
General Settings -> Language and input -> Option of Samsung keyboard -> Input languages
```

Here you can chose between many languages. So you have setted correctly.
Now to use one or the other language when you write is very easy, you have to slide with finger on the spacebar of the device keyboard.

Comment: AlessioMTX, this is nice. But the keyboard in focus is _external_ and _bluetooth_. What you've described is a virtual deveice's keyboard.

Comment: Not so, this works for a physical keyboard as well.

Answer (score 7):

You need to install physical keyboard layouts.
One of the best extensions to do that is this:

[RS - Hardware Keyboard Layouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tiagofalcao.raidsixinputdevices&hl=en)

It is free, and does nothing else. You use the standard settings page to select the hardware keyboard layout.

(It is mystery why Google does not provide the layout files by default.)

Comment: What is needed to get it to work? Doesn't show the option of 'physical keyboard' at Input\Language on Android 4.2.2 with Logitech Unifying K270. Thanks!

Comment: Answer no longer relevant without proper link.

Comment: The link given is dead: "**We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.**"

Answer (score 3):

You might wish to give the [External Keyboard Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo) a try. Take a look at this screenshot (click for large variant):

[image: External Keyboard Helper] [image: External Keyboard Helper Layouts]
<sup>External Keyboard Helper (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo); click images for larger variant)</sup>

That's just two of its setting screens. See the second entry in the first? *Chose keyboard layout*. That's what you are looking for. And it should only apply to the external keyboard, while leaving your "software keyboard" untouched.

Comment: I'm going to try this app ;) however I've done almost as asgeffchang wrote in his answer, and almost everything is ok, I have problem only with # and the character above N° 2 and 3, to switch between the languages I have to slide the finger on the space bar

Comment: I'd say you definitly want to give that app a try. The demo is a bit... um, well, demo, restricted (spacebar doesn't work; the dev even calls it "crippled"). Ratings sound more than just promising! // Don't forget to report back then :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest you [Russian Keyboard](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.androidteam.rukeyboard) app. It allows you to choose different layouts for hardware and software keyboards (one or multiple). It supports any layout (including your own). And it is free.

The only thing you should know is that selected layouts work as long as the app is selected as a current input method.

Answer (score 2):

Shift-Space works with an Apple Bluetooth Keyboard and a Samsung Tab 2 7.0. I included the languages I am using in the way that Mitro showed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using stock / default keyboard? Open the keyboard settings (in the keyboard, it's the cogwheel/gear icon to the left of the space bar). Go to `General settings > Input languages` and select English.

Comment: Would that change the input language *for the external keyboard only* (as requested)? To me that looks as if it would apply *globally*, i.e. also for the internal keyboard which Alession wants to remain Italian.

Comment: @Izzy Hmmm. I missed the word "only". That said, I'm not sure if it's possible to have different language settings for the internal and the external keyboard.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible *without external help*. I vaguely remember there was some app offering this... Yepp, found it :)

Answer (score 0):

Shift+Control works on my Apple Bluetooth Keyboard with my Asus Zenfone 5

Answer (score 0):

You should install extra keyboard layouts:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts
.

It is free and helps me to type on Mongolian language and included many other languages.