# Exotic key combos (e.g. for emacs) with bluetooth keyboard

Tags: ssh, external-keyboard

I recently bought a bluetooth keyboard (logitech, not sure of the exact model) for my Nexus 10 (on Android 4.3). It works nicely for everything except for some unusual key combos used in Emacs, such as control-Enter and control-/ (these don't work, just emit Enter and "/", repectively).

I'm using JuiceSSH to connect to a Linux host.

Has anyone found either ways to fix this or systematic ways to debug keyboard issues with Android & ssh?

Comment: Not sure whether it helps, but have you tried [External Keyboard Helper](http://www.appbrain.com/app/external-keyboard-helper-demo/com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo)? From its desc: *It supports a lot of different keylayouts also provides a lot of configuration options.* If it works, you will need the Pro (USD 2.50), but you can first try with the free "Demo" I've linked.

Comment: Yes, tried it already, although for a slightly different purpose (remapping caps lock to ctrl). As it seems, with the remapping switched on it just adds a few combos to the "not working" list, unfortunately. But thanks for the idea! :)

Comment: D'oh, that's sad news. And another sad one is I know of no other way... Wait: there's also [External Keyboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.medion.android.keyboard) to change the layout for external keyboards. Plus, in its desc it mentions *For Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) and newer physical keyboards are already supported by the system and can be configured in the system settings.* Have you checked that? // Related question: [Use bluetooth keyboard with a different layout?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/48837/16575)

Comment: More probably helpful sources: [The HTG Guide to Using a Bluetooth Keyboard with Your Android Device](http://www.howtogeek.com/175267/the-htg-guide-to-using-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-your-android-device/) plus, somewhat older (not sure if it's still applyable) [How to map android keys to your usb/bluetooth keyboard](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=159538). Maybe of use as well: [Customize external keyboard layout for Android](http://tech.viscomp.bg/customize-external-keyboard-layout-for-android/).

Answer (score 1):

I was was using ConnectBot as my ssh client, and was having similar troubles with emacs and a Bluetooth keyboard.  I couldn't execute several of the most important key mappings.

An ssh client called "serverauditor" was the fix for me.  I just connected with that instead, turned on my bluetooth keyboard, and everything worked!  No configuration headaches, and no external programs to remap my keyboard.

The only issue I had was Ctrl-Space for set-mark-command, but Ctrl-@ works fine as a substitute for the same command.

Comment: A link to "serverauditor" would make this question much more useful.

Comment: I just installed that app from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.server.auditor.ssh.client and it made things worse! Not only does the Alt key not work, but the Ctrl key doesn't either - whatever modifier keys are held down are ignored and just the plain letter is sent.