# how do I type special characters in ConnectBot?

Tags: terminal, external-keyboard

I use an Apple bluetooth keyboard with my android Nexus 5.

In ConnectBot I do not get the special chars when I use the Shift-key.

How can I type special chars like +_)(*&^ in the terminal?

Comment: Strange, a very similar question we had already a few hours back. So maybe you want to cross-check with [Exotic key combos (e.g. for emacs) with bluetooth keyboard](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/61545/16575)?