# Can we remap the keys when using an external keyboard?

Tags: external-keyboard

I'm using my physical keyboard on my tablet with Android. The Brazilian keyboard works fine for me, there are only two problems:

- The right-shift is "/" instead of shift.
- The "ˆ" is different and is not accepted by LaTeX. (In LaTeX, we use aˆb for exponetiation and this one doesn't work).

One possible fix is to be able to remap the keys, Is this possible? Is there some app that allows me to remap the keys?

Comment: There is a similar question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48837/use-bluetooth-keyboard-with-a-different-layout

Comment: Though you didn't specify "Bluetooth", the linked question fits precisely (including its answers).

Comment: FYI, I'm looking to remap the right windows key to be Ctrl (since there is no right Ctrl key on my bluetooth keyboard). This question has already been asked; so, instead of asking another one, I figured I'd let people know other kinds of answers (besides changing the whole layout) are in demand.

Answer (score 1):

Use GBoard (the Google Keyboard), it should be very easy.  Install this then when you are connected with the external keyboard, change the keyboard to Brazilian Portuguese and you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: I'm confused, do I "pass the keyboard keys through gboard"? I thought that when using external keyboard, the keys would go directly.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are saying.    Once you are connected with the external keyboard, go to the phone input settings and change the default keyboard to the one you want and the keyboard will type with that layout.

Comment: It didn't work. I changed to my language and Shift is still "/". I used multiples keyboard layouts and it didn't work.

Comment: What kind of android and hardware are you using?

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed with the link in the duplicate post. It's perfect now!